# Yarn workspaces not working as described by yarn team

Tags: hadoop-yarn, yarn-workspaces

I am working on a project using yarn workspaces. As I have never worked with this feature before I am trying to understand it by following the example setup on the yarn website (using yarn 1.22.19, so classic.yarnpkg.com).

It does the following:

1. create a **package.json** with the following content:

   ```
    {
      "private": true,
      "workspaces": ["workspace-a", "workspace-b"]
    }
   ```
2. create corresponding subfolders workspace-a and workspace-b
3. create a package.json for each individual workspace with the contents

   ```
    {
      "name": "workspace-a",
      "version": "1.0.0",

      "dependencies": {
        "cross-env": "5.0.5"
      }
    }
   ```

and

```
    {
      "name": "workspace-b",
      "version": "1.0.0",
  
      "dependencies": {
        "cross-env": "5.0.5",
        "workspace-a": 1.0.0
      }
    }
```

it now shows the folder structure how it is supposed to be:

```
/package.json
/yarn.lock

/node_modules
/node_modules/cross-env
/node_modules/workspace-a -> /workspace-a

/workspace-a/package.json
/workspace-b/package.json
```

and also that there isn't a package-b folder inside of node_modules.

Well, when following these steps, my structure is very different:

```
/package.json
/yarn.lock

/node_modules
/node_modules/cross-env
/node_modules/workspace-a -> /workspace-a
/node_modules/workspace-b -> /workspace-b

/workspace-a/node_modules/.bin (containes some scripts referencing the cross-env-package in the root node_modules folder)
/workspace-a/package.json

/workspace-b/node_modules/.bin (containes the same scripts referencing the cross-env-package in the root node_modules folder)
/workspace-b/package.json
```

Why is it different?

When following another tutorial which adds external and internal dependencies it also behaves different for me, when I install dependencies with e.g. `yarn workspace workspace-a add lodash` and `yarn workspace workspace-b add workspace-a@1.0.0` (won't work without versioning, which also seems to be a bug) all these dependencies are installed in the root node_modules, which, regarding to the tutorial, also shouldn't be the case.

So my question now is: is something wrong with my local yarn? If not, what else?